# How to configure Digits for WordPress to use with a custom SMS service provider?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, sms

I was trying to configure an SMS plugin. But I am pretty sure, I am doing something wrong.
Can anyone help me with the configuration?

**Information needed for the plugin:**

1. SMS Gateway URL
2. HTTP Header
3. HTTP Method
4. Gateway Parameters
5. Sender ID

**Information provided by the SMS service provider:**

1. API URL (GET & POST) : http://gsms.pw/smsapi?api_key=(APIKEY)&type=text&contacts=(NUMBER)&senderid=(Approved Sender ID)&msg=(Message Content)
2. api_key - API Key - Your API Key (C200095761d4749ec630f5.76399030)
3. type - text/unicode - text for normal SMS/unicode for Bangla SMS
4. contacts - mobile number - Exp: 88017XXXXXXXX+88018XXXXXXXX+88019XXXXXXXX...
5. msg - SMS body - N.B: Please use url encoding to send some special characters like &, $, @ etc

Screenshot of Plugin:

1. https://prnt.sc/25zpvl5
2. https://prnt.sc/25zq23q

Screenshot of SMS API:

1. https://prnt.sc/25zqbrj

The plugin is "Digits" by United Over for WordPress. The problem I am facing is, the SMS Gateway I am trying to use is not listed in this plugin. Moreover, I am not familiar with API stuff. So, I don't know what is HTTP Header, Gateway Parameters & I don't know how to write these codes correctly. But I have to write the HTTP Header in the correct format.

***The API Key I posted here is not correct.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We know nothing about this plugin, not even the name. We also don't know what problem you're having. Give us a clue...

Comment: @ADyson I forgot to mention the name of the plugin. My bad! It is "Digits" by United Over for WordPress. The problem I am facing is, the SMS Gateway I am trying to use is not listed in this plugin. Moreover, I am not familiar with API stuff. So, I don't know what is HTTP Header, Gateway Parameters & I don't know how to write these codes correctly. But I have to write the HTTP Header in the correct format.

Comment: So, presumably it's not working in some way, with the configuration you've got? Are you getting any errors in logs or anything, when you try to use it? Or it won't let you save the settings? Or what? What specifically is the problem?

Comment: Also, have you contacted the plugin provider for support? They should be able to give you documentation on how to configure it and what syntax to use, etc.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the reply. The configuration I got is 100% correct. The plugin is also working perfectly. I have searched for the documentation but their documentation is poor. They didn't cover the "Custom Gateway" part. Also, I have contacted for support but the license I had expired 3 months ago. So, they denied providing any support.

The problem is I don't know what is HTTP Header in API is. Also, I don't know how to write HTTP Header in the correct format. I am pretty sure that if I type the HTTP Header in plugin settings, the plugin will start working.

Comment: Which one is the HTTP Header in the configuration mentioned above(Information provided by the SMS service provider), and what is the correct format to write HTTP Header in the plugin settings?

Comment: The info provided by the SMS service provider in your screenshot does not specify anything about headers. You should check if they have any other documentation. But it looks like all the parameters for the gateway, including the API key, are supposed to be provided in the URL querystring. (IMHO that is a poor practice from a security point of view, but maybe they have a reason for it.)

Comment: @ADyson That means everything I see in the API URL provided by the provider has to be mentioned in the HTTP Header so that the plugin can read it and take action accordingly. Am I right? Or do I have to keep it smpty?

Comment: No, not in the header, it must be in the URL. Header and URL querystring are different. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview#http_messages

Comment: @ADyson As per your comment, I tried to put the API key in the SMS Gateway URL field. Now it is showing 1008 error. According to the documentation provided by the SMS service provider, 1008 means the message is empty. Till now I was getting 1003. It means API is not found. So, it seems the plugin starts to work partially. I kept HTTP Header empty. Now I am trying to figure out how to write Gateway Parameters. [Screenshot 2]

Comment: All the other parameters must be in the URL too. Look at the sample URL in the blue box at https://prnt.sc/25zqbrj

Comment: P.S. Can't you just use a gateway which the plugin supports directly? Probably a lot easier. They seem to support over 100 different providers

Comment: Dear @ADyson Thank you for your help. I figured it out. And it's working perfectly. Thank a lot.

Comment: That's great. Please post your solution below as an Answer, in case anyone else is struggling with it.

Comment: Sure I will do it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to configure Digits for WordPress for a custom SMS service provider?

In this case, we are using GSMS by Dianahost Ltd.
Dianahost is a Bangladeshi IT service provider.

1. Select Custom Gateway.
2. Copy and paste the API URL in "SMS Gateway URL" field.
3. Delete the following parameters from the API URL:

```
sender_id/sender_number
destination/to/contact/receiver
message/sms/msg
```

4. Now in the "Gateway Parameters" field you have to put the parameters you deleted from the API URL. Separate all parameters with commas and separate the value with `:`.(e.g: `contacts:{to},msg:{message},senderid:{sender_id}`).

Here "contacts" is a parameter provided by the SMS Service Provider and "to" is a value generated by the plugin.

5. Done!

Comment: `for a custom SMS service provider`...you should change that phrase to mention your specific SMS provider. The whole point of having custom settings is that they can be different for each provider, depending on how they require things. So this guidance will work for the specific provider you're using, but not necessarily for any others. Apart from that, good answer! P.S. `<br/>` doesn't work in Stackoverflow's markdown. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for info on how to format your posts.

Comment: Dear @ADyson Thank you! I have edited the answer and added the name of the provider along with their specific service name.

Comment: Thankyou, that makes it much more useful, since anyone searching regarding that provider name should now find this answer.

Comment: @ADyson Yes. And many thanks to you. You helped a lot. Without your help, this would have been much difficult for me to figure out what HTTP Header is. :)

Comment: No problem. There are quite a few blogs etc online which explain the different parts of a http request, including the MDN link I provided above. It would be good to familiarise yourself with the key concepts of HTTP if you are working with web applications